# How can make data of each table row into different query string and pass data to another view

Tags: javascript, string, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

As I have made the table body in my javascript which is shown in the below code. As I am new to programming, can anyone tell how to make data of each table row into querystring then pass to another page like html? Thank in advance

```
var Ref = firebase.database().ref().child("posts");
Ref.on("child_added", snap => {
  var name = snap.child("name").val();
 var region = snap.child("region").val();
  var form = snap.child("form").val();
  var code = snap.child("code").val();


  $("#table_body").append("<tr><td><a href='postlist.html?key='>" +       code  + "</td><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + region + "</td><td>" + form.  +"</a></td><td>");



  $("#table_body").off("click").on( "click", "tr", function() {

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use an HTML5 data attribute on each row to associate the table row with a record held in a persistent array. The click handler would read the data-attribute, pull the target row from the array in order to construct the URL.

So...

```js
const posts = []

const Ref = firebase.database().ref().child("posts")

Ref.on("child_added", snap => {
    posts.push({
        'name': snap.child("name").val(),
        'region': snap.child("region").val(),
        'form': snap.child("form").val(),
        'code': snap.child("code").val()
    })
})
```

Then, use that array to generate the table:

```js
posts.forEach((post, i) => {
    $("#table_body")
    .append(`
        <tr data-post-index="${i}">
            <td>${post.code}</td>
            <td>${post.name}</td>
            <td>${post.region}</td>
            <td>${post.form}</td>
        </tr>
    `);
})
```

I removed an `<A>` tag that was being used badly. You cannot start an `<A>` in one table cell and then close it in a different table cell. And, since it seems you want row-clicks to be handled using javascript, that anchor is superfluous.

Finally, let's set up the click handler. It will rely on the fact that each row has an HTML attribute that indicates the index of the full record in the array.

```js
$("#table_body").off("click").on( "click", "tr", function() {
    const postIndex = $(this).attr('data-post-index')
    const post = posts[postIndex]
    window.location = `postlist.html?key=${post.code}` // or whatever
});
```

**Warning**: it's been a while since I used jquery. I seem to recall that jquery event handlers receive the clicked element as `this`. If that's not the case, you might need to do a little more work inside that handler to identify the relevant `<TR>` from the event.

If that's the case, post a comment and I can dig into it. Or you could do a little research and figure it out yourself.